# Camel application design

Tags: apache-camel

Dear experienced Camel users! Please tell me

**1) What is wrong in my design in general? (I am sure it is not optimal)**

**2) What is a correct way to use POJOs in an Exchange body?**

My Grails web-application needs to interact to a remote web-service with some intermediate steps:

1. Create request xml
2. Validate this xml
3. Sign xml with dsig
4. Send signed xml to ths web-service
5. Validate response signature
6. Validate response XML
7. Process response

Each step may throw an exception, which must be shown at a page. Like this: "Error occured at step *StepName*, error message: *Message*".

So I guess my preferable pattern is "Request-Reply".

I am trying to assemble a camel route using a set of processors. Each processor is wrapped in .doTry() like this one.

```
from("direct:sendServiceCatalog")
    .doTry()
        .process(new Processor() {

            @Override
            public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("PROCESSING");
                throw new RuntimeException("Nice try");

            }
        })
        .to("mock:result")
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
        .process(
            new ExceptionStageDetectorProcessor(
                    SendServiceCatalogStage.FORM_XML))
        .to("mock:catch")
    .end();
```

ExceptionStageDetectorProcessor.java class is pretty simple:

```
public class ExceptionStageDetectorProcessor implements Processor {

    public ExceptionStageDetectorProcessor(SendServiceCatalogStage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public SendServiceCatalogStage getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    private SendServiceCatalogStage stage;

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Throwable caughtException = (Throwable) exchange
                .getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);

        exchange.getOut().setBody(new ProcessError(stage, caughtException));
    }
}
```

It almost worked! :)

The problem is that the new body *ProcessError* cannot be used, when exception occurs returning object is an error string, not a ProcessError object. If I try to set a simple string .setBody("FOO") returning object is "FOO" exactly.

Comment: Maybe because your Exception is casted to String

Comment: Any suggestions? And if you are here, maybe you can answer the first question, it's more important to me?